# While loop repeating but don't know why

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I am writing a program that reads the first 20 lines of a text file. When the first 20 lines are read, the user is given the option to continue reading the next 20 lines or to quit the program. What's happening me however is it prints the 20 lines, the user prompt comes up, and then it automatically prints the next 20 lines, without waiting for the user's input. After that, it will print the user prompt and then wait for the input. I know it's a simple issue but I'm not seeing it! I've amended the code a little bit as per replies to my question so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
FILE *fp;
char fname[20];
char c, input;
int line;
line = 0;

    printf("Please enter the name of the file you wish to view\n");
    scanf("%s", fname);

    fp = fopen(fname, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
    printf("The file did not open correctly");
    exit(0);
    }

    else
    {
    printf("The file opened correctly\n");
    }

        while(c != EOF && input != 'q')
        {   
            c = getc(fp);
            printf("%c", c);

                if  (c == '\n')
                {
                line++;

                    while (line==20)
                    {
                    line = 0;
                    printf("Press return to view the next 20 lines or press q to quit:");
                    scanf("%c", &input);

                        if (input == 'q')
                        {               
                            return 0;
                        }

                        else if (input == '\n')
                        {
                            line++;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would avoid statements like `line = line++`. Use either `line = line + 1` or `line++`, don't mix them. It doesn't look like that's your problem here, but it could cause issues in the future.

Comment: there's a lot or things wrong here, at first sight: using c and input unitialized, first line = 0 then line = 1, fname is only 20 characters, what if the user enters a longer name?, word is not used, the indentation makes no sense, there's if and else if but no else

Comment: `c` and `input` are used uninitialized.

Comment: I've initialized C and input at the start? Stijn, I know that there are a lot of minor errors at the minute regarding formatting etc but I need the program to work. That's my primary concern right now!

Comment: @adohertyd: See my edit for an update on the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
line = line++;
```

Postincrement, your line is always 0. Use just:

```
line++;
```

**Edit**: Ok, so this is not the problem. I've run your program and the problem is that when you enter the file name to the first scanf, you press enter so the program reads it. For some reason this enter (or newline) is read inside the second scanf as the input. Just add a dummy scanf after the first one to absorb this newline:

```
printf("Please enter the name of the file you wish to view\n");
scanf("%s", fname);
scanf("%c", &input); // dummy scanf
```

Comment: I thought about that as well, but the OP says that the prompt is printed, so it seems that the test `line == 20` succeeds every twenty lines

Comment: I would normally only use line++ was just trying out different things. The problem still remains however.

Comment: @Ken Wayne VanderLinde: Hmm it seems you are right... the line would be 0 only in java, in C it would work correctly.

Comment: @stijn, wait, don't shoot yet, I'm on the case and I've found his problem.

Comment: That's great Tudor thanks so much. That's a very unusual error. Would this kind of fix be considered as 'bad code'?

Comment: These are errors that any newbie to C encounters.
One should be very careful when using scanf, it has surprized me more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly, learn to **enable all warnings** and debug information (on linux, with `gcc -Wall -g`) and **learn how to use a debugger** (like `gdb` on Linux).

You really cannot learn to code in *C* without both.

Comment: We're being taught all of this as we go. I'm only 5 weeks into a C programming course. I'm sure we'll be taught debugging in time. Thanks though

Comment: Start learning to use now by yourself. If on Linux, GDB has a nice tutorial.

Comment: I'm on Windows using GCC compiler

Comment: If you can't use a debugger, you might temporily add `printf` statments each other line... like e.g. `printf("at source line %d c=%d\n", __LINE__, c);` but **using a debugger is much easier**

Comment: Well in this case everything seems to working ok except for the first loop repeating without waiting for user input. I use those printf statements in longer programs to find where errors are occurring but in this case I can't see where it would achieve anything

Comment: If you can't use a debugger and can't add debugging `printf`, you have to understand by yourself, with a pen and pencil (drawing and erasing what is happenning inside the computer), what is wrong. Asking other people to do your homework is harmful to you (and useless to them). A homework is supposed to teach you things.

Comment: I'm not asking people to do my homework. I've done 90% of the program myself. I came across an unusual error that has a fix above that I would never have been able to do myself no matter how hard I tried. I've learned a lot from this one question through constructive criticism from others. That is how I learn.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an fgets of stdin instead of scanf, you can specify the number of caracters you need to read and it's more secure.

Comment: I have been using fgets in other programs of a similar nature and I am much happier with that one however our lecturer wanted us to use getc for this particular one. I think I just made it harder on myself than it had to be! Thanks!